# Disable button via async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, promise

In my react.js component I render a button to create a PDF

```
<Button onClick={() => this.goCreatePdf()} variant="secondary" disabled={this.state.pdfLoading}>
   create PDF
</Button>
```

The button calls an async function which creates a PDF from data given to it and returns a Promise.

```
goCreatePdf() {
  this.setState({ pdfLoading: true });
  const pdfFinished = createPdf(this.Data);
  pdfFinished.then((response) => {
      this.finishedCreatePdf();
  });
}
```

When the PDF is finished another function is called to set pdfLoading to false.

```
finishedCreatePdf() {
  this.setState({ pdfLoading: false });
}
```

Unfortunately the button does not disable and enable like I want it to. Any suggestions?

**Edit**: I want the button to disable via the promise is unfullfilled.

Comment: _"Unfortunately the button does not disable and enable like I want it to"_ - what is the current behaviour? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Pease create a code example so that we can help you better.

Comment: I want the button to disable via the promise is pending.

Comment: @JanSchmidt What debugging have you done? Your code looks fine. Where exactly does it go wrong? Does `createPdf` run too fast so you don't even see the button flicker?

Comment: @Bergi I added a `consol.log(loading begins)` and `consol.log(loading finished)` directly befor `this.setState({ pdfLoading: true})` and after `this.setState({ pdfLoading: false})`. This seems to work proberly. Just the button is still active while I'm waiting.

Comment: Does your component's `render` method get called at all? Have you done anything special?

Comment: The component gets rendered as I want it to. Everything nice in place. The button is working and a PDF is created. The Button just does not disable. I use bootstrap. Maybe it's something about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. Have you checked carefully if you miss typing `pdfLoading` attribute of `state`?